# Media selectors "extending" bootstrap SASS classes

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, media-queries, scss-mixins

On a site I'm developing w/ Bootstrap/SASS (SCSS) I'd like to have a Bootstrap button group (`.btn-group`) become a vertical group (`.btn-group-vertical`) using media selectors, rather than JavaScript.  However, the well-known issues that `@extend` will not work inside a media selector, has left me befuddled.  E.g., this raises an error:

```
.navGroup {
    @extend .mt-1;
    @extend .btn-group;
    @include media-breakpoint-down(xs) {
        @extend .btn-group-vertical;
    }
}
```

If I were developing from scratch I'd rewrite `.btn-group` and `.btn-group-vertical` to simply `@include` a mixin, so that I could do something like:

```
.navGroup {
    @extend .mt-1;
    @include media-breakpoint-up(xs) {
        @include btn-group-include();
    }
    @include media-breakpoint-down(xs) {
        @include btn-group-vertical-include();
    }
}
```

I would rather not change the original bootstrap `_buttonGroup.scss` file, since it will be overwritten at the next release/update.  So I'm currently needing to copy and past the whole `.btn-group-vertical` definition:

```
.navGroup {
    @extend .mt-1;
    @extend .btn-group;
    @include media-breakpoint-down(xs) {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
        /* etc. for 70 lines */
    }
}
```

Is there a way to easily convert an existing class definition into a mixin within Sass that would solve such a problem?

Comment: Have you seen [this blog post?](https://www.sitepoint.com/cross-media-query-extend-sass/)

Comment: Yes, that would work if I were editing the _buttonGroup.scss file directly, but it doesn't work without editing the bootstrap files themselves, which is the main thing I'm trying to solve with the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the flex classes. Sorry, I don't know the markup for the navGroup.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

You can apply these per breakpoint. Checkout https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: awarding bounty as only answer -- it didn't solve the particular Q., but thanks Gavin for trying!